# Contacts app on new phone is not pulling in contacts from Google Account

Tags: sync, restore, google-contacts

According to Google help:

> If you save your contacts to your Google Account, they automatically show on your phone after you sign in.

My wife got a new Google Pixel 4a and successfully added her Google Account, but no contacts appear in the Contacts app. Needless to say, this mean that all phone numbers have to added manually for calls or text. Gmail contacts still autocomplete.

We've tried following some of the suggestions at Google's [Fix account sync issues](https://support.google.com/pixelphone/answer/6212917) page, including:

1. Manually sync your Google Account
2. Remove & re-add your account

Neither one has solved the problem.

How do we get the Contacts app to populate with all the contacts in the Google Account?

Comment: What does the contacts synchronization status show for the Google account?

Comment: It shows a last-synced time for when the Google Account was added.